# Quantum decoherence and the which way double slit expirment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, superposition, decoherence

Using the detector to find which way the particle goes makes the particle become entangled with the detector which destroys coherence meaning the 2 superposition states can't ineract with one another.

Now my questions are:

1. What pair of entangled particles have the longest decoherence time  (time for the coherence to disappear completely).
2. We know that the 2 superposition states can't ineract with one another due to decoherence, but can they ineract with anything else (that can be detected Expirmentaly)? 
   Perhaps it could interact with themselves if each was passed through a further double slit?